# Error Message "GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST"

Tags: php, laravel

When I was click submit button I got an error message .

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> POST

I have try this method, but still error.

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

This my code

```
<form action="{{ route('pemesanan.process') }}" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  ...
  ...
</form>
```

For route

```
Route::post('pemesanan/process', ['as' => 'pemesanan.process', 'uses' => 'PemesananController@process'])->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: you're using wrong route name, your route is `pemesanan.calculate` & in form you have used `pemesanan.process`

Comment: will be `{{ route('pemesanan.calculate') }}`

Comment: oh sorry, this is my route `Route::post('pemesanan/process', ['as' => 'pemesanan.process', 'uses' => 'PemesananController@process'])->middleware('auth');`

Comment: @CBroe in Route: post (...) is used to process booking payments

Comment: If a GET request is made, despite the form having `method="post"`, then someting else must be going on. Check what is actually happening using your browser dev tools (network panel) - is it making a GET request right away, or is there a POST request happening first, and then a redirect causing a subsequent GET request maybe? Are you submitting this form normally, or is AJAX involved? Does the console show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

your route name is **"pemesanan.calculate"** but you are using **"pemesanan.process"** in your form

change your form to solve your problem

Comment: oh sorry, this is my route `Route::post('pemesanan/process', ['as' => 'pemesanan.process', 'uses' => 'PemesananController@process'])->middleware('auth');`

Comment: are you logged in?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: you are using auth middleware. which requires you to be logged in

Comment: yeah i was logged in